# Getting different skeleton each time invoke Express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The first time typing "express" in console to create a web skeleton of nodejs, in the index.js file, I got something like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

After that, for another usage, I invoke "express" again to create another web skeleton, and I got different source code in the index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

The content in app.js is the same.

Why did I get this differences in source code of index.js on different time invoke "express"? Are they different express-generator version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you generated the first one with 3.x series and the latter on 4.x? `Router` was introduced in Express 4.0.

You could verify this by checking out `package.json` of each project. That should contain the version of Express for you to compare.